# Is there a way to hide some part of your code on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using sqlalchemy and psycopg to run SQL inside Python. However, there's a part of the code I want to hide when sending to other people (my passwords). Is there a way to do this?

This is how I sent to my colleagues last time, but the parts with **XXXXXX** were inserted by hand, I want to automate this:

```
import os
import sqlalchemy

pd.options.display.max_columns = 500
pd.options.display.max_rows = 500
from datetime import timedelta

import psycopg2
import csv

DB_USER = 'XXXXXX'
DB_PASS = 'XXXXXX'
DB_HOST = 'XXXXXX'
DB_PORT =  XXXXXX
DB_NAME = 'xxxxxx'

def get_engine():
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_NAME))

def run_query(query_txt):
    engine = get_engine()
    with engine.begin() as con:
        return pd.read_sql(query_txt, con)
```

I found some related posts, like [hide code in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255288/hide-code-in-jupyter-notebook) and [Hide selected code cells in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56458584/hide-selected-code-cells-in-jupyter-notebook), but they didn't answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is the appropriate answer, but you may store the part in another `.py` file under the same directory, and call it every time. For example, the file with name `name.py` can look like:

```
DB_USER = 'asdf'
DB_PASS = 'yxc'
DB_HOST = 'asdf'
DB_PORT =  23
DB_NAME = 'sdfdsfds'
```

In your current jupyter notebook, you can safely delete these lines but access the variables by:

```
from name import *
DB_USER
```

gives you:

```
'asdf'
```

Comment: yep, that's a good idea! Thanks, upvoted and checked as the correct answer.